# Can multiple goroutines have connections to the same rabbitmq exchange at the same time without being shared?

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I'm trying to set up consumers for topics that are published to our exchange, like an API gateway that publishes messages to one of several subscribers.

I can't find an example of multiple subscribers that aren't just put in the main function of a single file.

1. Can I create a goroutine for each consumer without breaking the connection that every other consumer has?
2. Is a channel inside a goroutine appropriate within another goroutine?

Here is the main file:

```
package main

func main() {

    ...

    go myMessagePackage.Subscribe("example_topic1")
    go myMessagePackage.Subscribe("example_topic2")
    go myMessagePackage.Subscribe("example_topic3")

    ...

}
```

And this is what each consumer looks like:

```
package myMessagePackage

import...

func Subscribe(topic string, queueName string)  {

    conn, err := amqp.Dial(getConnectionString())
    failOnError(err, "API Consumer failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "API Consumer failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    err = ch.ExchangeDeclare(
        env.RabbitMq_Exchange_Name,
        env.RabbitMq_Exchange_Type,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
    failOnError(err, "API Consumer failed to declare an exchange")

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        queueName,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
    failOnError(err, "API Consumer failed to declare a queue")

    err = ch.QueueBind(
        q.Name,
        topic,
        env.RabbitMq_Exchange_Name,
        false,
        nil)
    failOnError(err, "API Consumer failed to bind a queue")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name,
        "",
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
    failOnError(err, "API Consumer failed to register a consumer")

    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {
            log.Printf("API Consumer received a message from backend: %s", d.Body)
            routeResponse(d.Body)
        }
    }()

    log.Printf("API Consumer on topic %s started. Waiting for messages.", topic)
    <-forever
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Is a channel inside a goroutine appropriate within another goroutine?"  This sentence doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: My best guess is that you're under the incorrect assumption that a goroutine can somehow be within another goroutine. If this is your question, then your understanding of goroutines is flawed. If you mean something else, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, yes they can, why wouldn't they? each routine declares the exchange + queue (which in RMQ terms means: create if not exists), and you get a channel from the queue that is bound to said exchange. All this means is that you'll consume N messages (each message is consumed exactly once) concurrently.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this approach. Have you run into some issue when running it?